# virtualenv can't find modules

Tags: python-3.x, flask, virtualenv

So I had been working with virtualenvs a couple months ago but had to stop for a while and now I don't seem to be able to get it working again.

Here is what I did

```
D:\CS\Python_Projects\HomeCenter>venv\Scripts\activate
(venv) D:\CS\Python_Projects\HomeCenter>pip freeze
You are using pip version 6.0.8, however version 7.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.0
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.8
MarkupSafe==0.23
SQLAlchemy==1.0.8
waitress==0.8.9
Werkzeug==0.10.4

(venv) D:\CS\Python_Projects\HomeCenter>server.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\CS\Python_Projects\HomeCenter\server.py", line 3, in <module>
    from waitress import serve
ImportError: No module named 'waitress'

(venv) D:\CS\Python_Projects\HomeCenter>
```

Same happens if I were to run app.py, it won't find flask. I have been using PyCharm and when I check there it tells me the interpreter is pointing towards 3.4.2 virtualenv at D:\CS\Python_Projects\HomeCenter\venv

So why can't it find the modules?

Oh contents of server.py in case it's relevant

```
from waitress import serve
import os
from app import app

port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 9999))
serve(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Comment: What happens if you run `python server.py` instead?

Comment: The same thing however, when I do venv\Scripts\python.exe server.py then it works.

So I was just being silly it seems

Comment: That means you are running your application with a different interpreter. It sounds like your PATH is screwed up. To avoid this, it's recommended that you don't use pip directly. Instead, use `python -m pip` (e.g., `venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install [library_name]`).

Answer (score 0):

Hello I am korean student so I can't English not well. Please understand.
In my case, I have a well operated program but suddenly occured "not found" error like you after update mac os to BigSur.
but I finally found solution.
when before update I compiled by "source venv/fileName.py" but after update I compile by "python3 venv/fileName.py" then well operate

You try it too.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things could have happened here:

1. Use `which python` and `which pip` to check if both are from the virtual env itself.
2. As [dirn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/978961/dirn) suggested in the comments, it might be a PATH mixup. The packages were installed in the virtual environment but the script was executed from outside the environment interpreter. (Use `venv\Scripts\python.exe <filename.py>` instead of just filename to execute).